# How can display correct Chinese word from the python script using subprocess

Tags: python, curl, character-encoding, subprocess, python-2.x

Cannot display correct Chinese word from the python script

Python code

```
import subprocess
import re

strCmdResult = subprocess.Popen("curl -vvv 'http://xxxx.xxxx.xxxx/xxxx/xxxx.js?r=0071563892276000' -H 'Referer: http://xxx.xxx.xxx'", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
print strCmdResult
```

Output

```
rq[56]="1739907^1^11^45^▒▒▒▒▒Ρ▒~▒▒▒▒^27633,24230^▒ڶ▒▒▒ϣ▒▒▒▒Ŭ▒▒ŵ▒▒▒▒^6687323^";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the file is encoded either the gbk or gb18030 [encoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).

Both produce this output for that particular line:

> "1732948^1^1^85^洛迪高阿古利 (助攻:A.華倫西亞)^84828^洛迪高阿古利 (助攻:A.瓦伦西亚)^6687325^25000"

The other encodings listed for Chinese fail to decode the data.

You can decode like this:

```
strCmdResult = subprocess.Popen("curl -vvv 'http://xxx.xxxx.xxx/xxxx/xxx.js?r=0071563892276000' -H 'Referer: http://xxxx.xxx.xxx'", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
decoded = strCmdResult.decode('gbk')
print decoded
```

Answer (score 1):

Use utf-8 charset in your python code :

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Code goes here
```

Use utf-8 charset in your [request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Charset)

You may need to [encode/decode](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#the-string-type) your String results